# Ansible replacing a value in sshd_config

Tags: ansible

All I am tearing my hair out trying to get the Ansible lineinfile module to behave. I am certain that I am misunderstanding what it is supposed to do and when. Every now and then we need to push out an updated sshd_config file. However, we have some machines that use non-standard ports. To capture those ports I use this piece of code:

```
- name: Get SSH port
  shell: cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config | grep -w Port | awk '{print $2 }'
  args:
    executable: /bin/bash
  register: ssh_port
  become: yes

- name: Setting insert line value
  set_fact:
    insline: "Port {{ ssh_port.stdout }}"
```

After copying the new config file I then try to use lineinfile like this:

```
- name: Edit sshd_config to insert custom port
  lineinfile:
    path: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
    regex: '^(.*)Port(.*)$'
    line: '{{ insline }}'
    backrefs: yes
  become: yes
```

Instead of overwriting the existing #Port with the actual port being used it places the Port line down further in the body of the config file. Any ideas as to why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that your regular expression isn't sufficiently specific. You're looking for any line that contains the word `Port`, which includes, for example, the `GatewayPorts` configuration line. I suspect this is what the expression is matching.

If you want to replace a line containing `Port`, then do something like this:

```
- lineinfile:
    path: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
    regex: '^#?Port '
    line: '{{ insline }}'
    backrefs: yes
```

That will match a line that looks like `#Port`  or a line that looks
like `Port` , and nothing else.

---

As an aside, you can replace this expression:

```
shell: cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config | grep -w Port | awk '{print $2 }'
```

with this:

```
command: awk '/^Port / {print $2}' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```